# How can I take separate parts of one String when reading a text file to be used for setting an instance of String object?

Tags: java, performance, text-files

One line from my text file (Students.txt) looks like this:

```
[Down Shirlee 1424 7185765304 HIS, BUS429, WRT008, PED105, ENG34, HIS534,A, KOR380,C, WRT837,C, CSE673,A, ENG475,C-, CIV561,B-, MAT318,C+, CIV796,A-, MUS586,A, HIS281,B, CHE314,A-, PHI353,B+ 2.53]
```

The format for each line in the Students.txt file is as follows:

```
first name, last name, unique id, phone number, major, coursesToTake, coursesTaking, coursesTaken, gpa
```

Now I need to take each argument (first name, last name, id, etc) and use it to create a Student object which is then added to an array of Students---> Student[] bag.

At first, my plan was this:

```
File file = new File("src/Students.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
Student s = new Student();
i = 2000;
Student[] bag = new Student[i];

for(int p=0; p<i; p++){
    String fName; 
    String str = in.nextLine();

    for(int q=0; q<str.length(); q++){
        String fName += str[q];
        if(str[q] == " ");
            s.setFirstName(fName);

    }       

    //bag[p] = s;
}
```

The obvious problem with this method is after I get the first name, how do I continue the loop to get the rest of the arguments?
Since eventually, after each iteration on the first for loop:

```
for(int p=0; p<i; p++)
```

The

> Student s

object would have all the proper arguments from the text file to which I can then:

```
studentBag[p] = s;
```

But after I get the first name, I do not understand how to get the rest of the arguments. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split by comma:

```
String[] args = line.split(",");
String name = args[0];
String secondNAme = args[1];
.....
Student s = new Student(name, secondNAme, ....)
```

Comment: Would I be able to do this?                                                                           
                        `String str = in.nextLine();
   String[] args = str.split(" ");
   String fName = args[0]; 
   String lName = args[1];
   String id = args[2]; `

Comment: It worked. I was not aware of the line.split() method. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Although the existing answer is correct, do you really need to implement this yourself?

Using a library like OpenCSV - http://opencsv.sourceforge.net - you can declare your class, annotate your fields with the column headings in the data and let it do all the work for you.

Not only is the code likely to be more readable, but also more stable, too. For a start, how do you handle if a quoted comma appears in your input data?